# framebuffer starts with the wrong resolution, but is fixed by opening settings or running xrandr

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, display-resolution, xrandr

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-47-generic) on a HP dv6500, with a core 2 duo and GMA 965 graphics. I had to reinstall recently, and when I log in, the display resolution is set incorrectly. However, whenever I open settings or run xrandr to see what's going on, the display resizes correctly. Here is the output of `xrandr`.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2128 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800      60.00*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
   640x400       60.00  
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  848x480 (0xac) 29.027MHz
        h: width   848 start  849 end  912 total  944 skew    0 clock  30.75KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  512 total  513           clock  59.94Hz
```

Here is the output of `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`, which shows the resizing after I run `xrandr`.

```
[  2360.400] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  2360.400] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  2360.400] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2361.319] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 10100
[  2361.319] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  2361.319] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.11  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 -hsync -vsync (49.4 kHz eP)
[  2361.639] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x800@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2370.939] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 2128x800
[  2370.954] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 848x480@59.9 on TV1 using pipe 1, position (1280, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  4274.215] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1280x800
```

Any idea what is going on here?

EDIT: added output of `xrandr`. I would like to know why my screen is being read as 2128x800 and not 1280x800 as it is supposed to be - and how to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know what is going, or how to fix it? The first one is most likely a small bug. To fix (workaround) please [edit] and add the output of xrandr.

Comment: @JacobVlijm , I have added the `xrandr` output, as well as clarified that I would like to know how to fix the problem.